# is there any tool to reverse engineer docorated C# probuff-net class file to .proto file

Tags: protocol-buffers

Bellow code is C# decorated code from protobuf-net.

```
    using ProtoBuf;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    namespace Lib
    {
    [Serializable]
    [ProtoContract]
    public class CAcct
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int Acct { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public DateTime BalDt { get; set; }      
//Serialize bytes to object 
        public byte[] Serialize()
        {
            return CUtility.ProtoSerialize<CAcct>(this);
        }
//DeSerialize bytes to object 
        public CAcct DeSerialize(byte[] bytes)
        {
            return CUtility.ProtoDeserialize<CAcct>(bytes);
        }  
     }
    }
```

Need help in producing .proto file to consume this for java implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string proto = Serializer.GetProto<CAcct>();
```

However! `DateTime` is a royal PITA for x-plat unless you are happy to change to the new "well known" timestamp type. If you can do that **noting that it will change your data layout** (so will break compatibility) - add `DataFormat = DataFormat.WellKnown` to your `[DataMember(...)]`.

This "well known" timestamp type didn't exist when I first added the `DateTime` handling, and I chose a different layout. Note that the "well known" format requires recent builds.

---

If you change the `DateTime` property to:

```
[ProtoMember(2, DataFormat = DataFormat.WellKnown)]
public DateTime BalDt { get; set; }
```

Then the .proto schema becomes (as proto2):

```
syntax = "proto2";
package Lib;
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message CAcct {
   optional int32 Acct = 1 [default = 0];
   optional .google.protobuf.Timestamp BalDt = 2;
}
```

or (as proto3);

```
syntax = "proto3";
package Lib;
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message CAcct {
   int32 Acct = 1;
   .google.protobuf.Timestamp BalDt = 2;
}
```

Either of which should work just fine with Java without any pain.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on Datetime.  I am unable to print DateTime data type using Java or de-serialize the value with in a class.

Comment: @Ravinda are you able to change your existing model? That would be the most convenient option. To do that just add the "well known" flag (as above) and tell Java you're using Timestamp

Comment: Sorry, can you give an example,  should I add into Bcl.proto file or In .CS file ? I have directly used Bcl.proto and compiled with protoc for java.  Bcl.java is ready and I am unable to retrieve the DateTime format. DateTime  d = object.getBalDt(); retrieves a long value.  I think this has a reference to actual values. I am not sure how to parse and get the readable format.  any advise ?

Comment: @Ravindra right; let me say again: if at all possible, you **do not** want to use bcl.proto for this if at all possible. I've edited my answer to me much more explicit about the steps to follow to use `Timestamp`. If you don't have the option of changing your data format, then it is *possible* to use bcl.proto, but it is really really inconvenient

Comment: Did try the DataFormat.WellKnown.  I receive the data in seconds  (Example BalDt { seconds : 35126 } instead of BalDt { 2/1/2018 12:00:00 AM }. )  I need to retrieve the BalDt Data as 2/1/2018 12:00:00 AM.... please advice

Comment: @Ravindra do you have an example input and output? was it actually 35126? or was it a much bigger number? for example, if I do a test locally: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/317c63cc3aaae68d40e0a3141baba28f - now; emphasis: we're transferring data here, not formatting - formatting doesn't exist in pure data. All we care about is getting the right value. So: do you have an *actual example*, with fake data and ideally the binary, that produces an unexpected result? What API are you using in Java to get the result you're seeing? From what I can see: protobuf-net got everything correct.